# geom_vline() with date gives Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

After getting `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` messages with `ggplot` and `geom_vline()` I did some experimenting and found the following surprise.

Here's a reproducible example that starts with some data:

```
require(lubridate)
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  date=dmy(c("2/6/2014", "3/6/2014", "4/6/2014", "5/6/2014")),
  value=1:4
)
```

Let's plot that with a vertical line through `"3/6/2014"`:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(dmy("3/6/2014")), linetype=4)
```

[image: Illustration of ggplot, date and vline issue]

However, if we change the order of the geoms:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=value)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(dmy("3/6/2014")), linetype=4) +
  geom_line()
```

the following error message is produced:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Comment: I agree that this is a bit of an oddity in how ggplot is deciding to train scales. If you really need `geom_vline` to be first (e.g. if you need lots of other stuff to be plotted on top of it) you could always add `geom_blank` immediately after `ggplot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just convert date to Date class and add `scale_x_date()`, like this:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=value)) + geom_line() +
geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date(dmy("3/6/2014"))), linetype=4) +
scale_x_date()
```

Comment: Hmmm... this gives me a "Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only"